# Display Data Using TextBox On A Form From Another Form

Tags: ms-access

How to display a username on the top left corner.The user will be login on the login form after that when he enter the menu. Is there a way to display what is his username on the top left corner using textbox ? (Using VBA)

My Current Code

```
Dim Name As String
Name = DLookup("FullName", "tblIC", "frmlog.txtIC.value=" & "IC")
Me.txtName.value = Name
```

The Code doesn't work.
Im trying to write a code in FrmMenu textbox to dlookup from Frmlog.
As in FrmLog the user will enter their UserName then in FrmMenu the top left corner will show their full name and userid.

How do i dlookup so that it will use the requirement in FrmLog for FrmMenu ?

Comment: Yes. Either bind the form to dataset and filter record to the user record. Or use VBA code to set textbox value or label caption. Your question is too broad.

Comment: What VBA code can i use to do it ?

Comment: I don't know your db so cannot advise specifics. Login procedure is a common topic. Do research and when you have code with issue post question. Start with http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23585

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example the `DLookup()` function on the load event of the form if the user name is in a table:

```
Dim userName As String
userName = DLookup("ColumnName", "YourTableName", "YourCriteria = 1")
Me!UserNameTextbox.Value = userName
```

Another mehtod to get the username direct from the pc environment would be:

```
Dim userName As String
userName = Environ("USERNAME")
```